# Compartir proyecto .exe java a otra pc sin tener que instalaar el jre

Tags: java, jar, exe

quisiera saber como puedo compartir mi proyecto que hice en java. Lo pase para .jar pero para este a quien se lo iba a dar tenia que tener java instalado por eso quise pasarlo a un .exe pero sucedia lo mismo ya que necesitaba el jre para ejecutarlo, habia intentado vaarias maneras como agregar toda la carpeta de jre incluso el jdk al hacer un instador pero aun asi cuando lo pasaba a la otra pc este no funcionaba, llevo muchos dias con esto y quisiera que me ayudaran por favor

Comment: Hola JCarlos, Bienvenido, no creo que sea fácil de hacer, se que hay varias herramientas que lo hacen, yo solo se un nombre: launch4j, está [aqui](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) y hay un servicio online [aqui](https://genuinecoder.com/online-converter/jar-to-exe/), no los probé, ni tengo referencias.

Comment: @MarcePuente use el launch4j pero aun asi no ejecuta en la otra pc y solo se ejecuta si se tiene el jdk y con el jre no ejecuta

Comment: Has usado la versión en linea?, porque creo que es una versión recortada.

Comment: lo dudo mucho que sea eso

Answer (score 0):

Como te mencionaron en los comentarios puedes utilizar launch4j, yo lo ocupe para unos juegos que realicé con libgdx siguiendo instrucciones en videos de youtube como este [How to convert jar to exe using Launch4J Full explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyMPPuYGN-U) espero lo puedas entender ya que esta en inglés.

Todavía tengo la carpeta guardada de aquellos tiempos, además de generar el .exe se generaran muchos más archivos que se guardarán en carpetas y el peso de tu aplicación aumentará considerablemente mi .jar era de aproximadamente 10~20MB y la carpeta para ejecutarlo sin tener el jre instalado pesa casi 230MB.

Debes tener en cuenta que esa carpeta que se llama jre no tiene el mismo contenido que la de un jre original ya que es modificada por el Launch4J y por lo menos el ejecutable funciono sin problemas en windows XP y win 10 que no tenían Java instalado.

[image: carpeta final]

Comment: Pon la explicación del video _en la respuesta_. Piénsalo: si más adelante alguien llega a tener el mismo problema, y el enlace cae, ¿cómo podrá sacar provecho de tu respuesta? Lee [answer].

Comment: no se realmente que sucedio pero al añadir el jre con launch4j el programa no ejecutaba a pesar que lo hacia en mi pc, teniendo el jdk y jre instalado, solo funcionaba si agregaba el jdk en el apartado del jre pero al compartir este .exe si a quien se lo daba no lo tenia instalado el jdk este no ejecutaba.

Answer (score 0):

[Java depende de una máquina virtual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html) para funcionar. Por lo tanto es imposible ejecutar Java sin una. Esta máquina virtual viene con el JRE.

La única forma de que un programa funcione sin ejecutables externos es compilándolo al único lenguaje que el procesador es capaz de entender, código máquina.

Tampoco es **la solución definitiva** ya que depende del sistema operativo y puede no funcionar con otros procesadores. Por lo tanto tendrás que compilar el programa para cada combinación.

En [esta publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25617961/13419694) sugieren que uses un compilador de Java bytecode a código máquina o incluso un conversor de código Java a C/C++.

Comment: mi intencion es compartir la aplicacion sin que el otro tenga  que instalar el jre o el jdk pero en mi caso solo ejecutaba si incluia con requisito el jdk (no le agregaba el jdk al .exe)

Comment: Entiendo y gracias, pero creo que es algo mas el problema porque el jre practicamente no lo hace ejecutar en cambio el jdk si, pero lo que quiero es que se pueda ejecutar sin necesidad de instalar estos dos.

Comment: ¿Obtienes algún error? El JRE contiene lo necesario para ejecutar programas escritos en Java. El JDK es para desarrollar en Java y también contiene el JRE.

Comment: ese es el problema, tengo error a pesar que uso el jre

Comment: @JCarlos cuál error?